# Ajax query works with dataType:'text' fails with dataType:'text/xml; charset=utf-8'

Tags: ajax, xml, xml-parsing

When I try to do an Ajax query with dataType of 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'... I get a parsererror.

1. The xml response is valid xml
2. The response header shows a Content-Type of 'text/xml;
   charset=utf-8'.
3. It's not a cross domain request

These three problems were answers in other parsererror questions.

My ajax looks like this:

```
        $('#submitLogin2').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = $('#loginForm2').serialize();
            var url = 'http://somewhere.com/Api2.0/Session_Create.aspx';
            $.ajax({
                url: url, type: "POST", dataType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
                data: formData, contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#loginResult').html(data.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;').replace(/\n/g, '<br />'));
                },
                error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                    alert(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
                }
            });
        });
```

And the response is:

```
<Response><Error code='0'>Invalid User Name or Password</Error></Response>
```

It's great that the 'text' request works... but it would be nice to let Ajax parse the xml for me. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings - dataType "xml" is supported.

Changing your query to following should give you expected result:

```
url: url, type: "POST", dataType: 'xml',
```

Comment: Weird how so many samples have 'text/xml'... but 'xml' by itself worked... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have also to parse the XML response to process it as string with something like $.parseXML(data) or a XMLSerializer. I think this is even more important, hence the response dataType should be automatically determined by the MIME type.